# Delete whitespace in filenames in directory

Tags: linux, files, rename

I have a directory where some filenames have been wrongly named `something .pdf` rather than `something.pdf`. Is there a quick one liner I can use to delete the whitespace in the filenames.

I have tried `find -name "* .pdf" -type f | rename 's/  //g'`

but this did not work.

Comment: `rename` expects the file name as 2nd parameter, not as input. So instead of piping to it, use `find`'s `-exec` parameter to call `rename`. But `rename` accepts multiple file name parameters, so if recursion in subdirectories is not needed, just `rename 's/ //g' *\ .pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I couldn't get `rename 's/ //g' *\ .pdf` but have used `rename ' ' '' *.pdf` instead.

Comment: So your `rename` implementation is the one from the _util-linux_ package. Based on the syntax you used in the question looked like it's the one which comes with Perl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In zsh, this is easily done with the [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function. Put `autoload -U zmv` in your `~/.zshrc`, or run this once in your shell, then:

```
zmv '* .pdf' '${f// /}'
```

This removes all spaces from the file name. If you only want to remove the one before the `.pdf` extension:

```
zmv '* .pdf' '${f# .pdf}.pdf'
```

or using parentheses to delimit groups that can be used as backreferences:

```
zmv '(*) .pdf' '$1.pdf'
```

If you want to act in subdirectories as well:

```
zmv '**/* .pdf' '${f# .pdf}.pdf'
```

or (note that you have to use `(**/)`, not `(**)/`):

```
zmv '(**/)(*) .pdf' '$1$2.pdf'
```

---

Under Linux, with or without zsh, if there is only this one spurious space in the file names:

```
rename \ .pdf .pdf *\ .pdf
```

or, if there's only this one space in the original names:

```
rename ' ' '' *\ .pdf
```

If you want to act in subdirectories as well, in ksh93 ≥o+ or bash ≥4, you can use `**` to match files in subdirectories. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first (put this line in your `~/.bashrc`) and `set -o globstar` in ksh93.

```
rename \ .pdf .pdf **/*\ .pdf
```

Beware that bash follows symlinks when recursing directories.

Without the benefit of `**`, you can use `find` to recurse.

```
find . -name '* .pdf' -exec rename ' .pdf' .pdf {} +
```

Under Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu) and most non-Linux systems that ship with `perl`, the `rename` command is a different one, which takes a Perl expression as an argument instead of a string to replace and a replacement string. Either use `rename.ul` in the commands above (under Debian and derivatives), or with the Perl `rename`:

```
rename 's/ \.pdf$/.pdf/' -- *\ .pdf    # strip the space before the extension
rename 's/ //g' -- *\ .pdf             # strip all spaces
```

Comment: +1 for being so thorough and covering more than one tool. All of your answers are incredible, by the way. I've learned a lot from them in the past few months.

Comment: Note that the `rename ... *\ .pdf` ones will fail if there are pdf files whose name starts with `-` unless `POSIXLY_CORRECT=` is in the environment. You need the `--` to avoid it, but that should go *before* the non-option arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This will protect against accidental overwrite, if that's important.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find . -name '* .pdf')
do
  mv -i "$i" "${i% .pdf}.pdf"
done
```

If you run this in an interactive shell you might want to exit it immediately since you change IFS.